# Complex SQL query

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have need to write a query which is a little complicated for me to put together. The basic idea is to match a couple of fields from different tables and then edit another table based on the result.

There are three tables involved:

Schedules: `sch_id, date, schedule, event_id`

Link_Location_Schedules: `id, loc_id, sch_id`

Link_Location_Events: `id, loc_id, event_id`

Now what I need to try and do is:

1. find schedules that are set after todays date in "Schedules".
2. for these schedules get location ids from `Link_Location_Events` where `event_ids` equal the schedule event id.
3. for each of the matched schedules (`sch_id`) and returned locations (`loc_id`) check if the pair already exist in the `Link_Location_Schedules`, if not insert them.

Here are some SQL queries I have done for the above, I just need to combine them some how:

1. `SELECT sch_id FROM 'Schedules' WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sports_schedule_insert_date_time, "%Y-%m-%d") >= '2012-11-14';`
2. `SELECT loc_id from Link_Location_Events, Schedules WHERE Link_Location_Events.event_id = Schedules.event_id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like a simple insert from select statement...

```
insert into Link_Location_Schedules
   ( loc_id,
     sch_id )
select
      PreQuery.loc_id,
      PreQuery.sch_id
   from
      ( select
              s.sch_id,
              lle.loc_id
           from
              Schedules s
                 join Link_Location_Events lle
                    on s.event_id = lle.event_id ) PreQuery
      LEFT JOIN Link_Location_Schedules lls
         on PreQuery.loc_id = lls.loc_id
        and PreQuery.sch_id = lls.sch_id
   where
      lls.loc_id is null
```

The innermost prequery is to get all possible schedule / location IDs.  From that, left-join to the existing location/schedules on those found.  Then, the WHERE clause will return only those where NO MATCH WAS FOUND (thus the lls.loc_id is null).  Take that result and insert directly into the schedule / location table.

Comment: Thank you for this answer ... I don't think I could have come up with that. I will give it a try.